# Deploy Docker Compose from different repositories

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github

I have 3 separate repositories, which contains API, web app, and Admin projects. All 3 runs on a Digital Ocean docker machine, and I deploy the 3 using docker-compose (I want to keep things simple).

Every time a push to master with a tag happen, GithubActions build each separate project and publish a docker image (with the corresponding tag), and then I manually launch `docker compose up -d`. The docker compose file point to the latest version of each image, so it get automatically reloaded and launched.

Is there a better way to automatically reload the docker compose from GitHub Actions? I ideally want that each time a repository build an image and push it to the registry, the docker compose automatically reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize watchtower to restart the specified containers each time new image of that container is avaialble.

> [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower) : with watchtower you can update the running version
> of your containerized app simply by pushing a new image to the Docker
> Hub or your own image registry. Watchtower will pull down your new
> image, gracefully shut down your existing container and restart it
> with the same options that were used when it was deployed initially.
> Run the watchtower container with the following command:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d \
>     --name watchtower \
>     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
>     containrrr/watchtower
> ```

docker-compose integration example:

```
services:
  watchtower:
    command: --label-enable --cleanup --interval 300
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
    network_mode: none
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  mariadb:
      depends_on:
        - watchtower
      env_file: .mariadb.env
      image: mariadb:10
      labels:
        - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true"
      networks:
        - default
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./data/volumes/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
```

To check the logs of the updation you can execute `docker-compose logs watchtower`

docker-compose integration reference: https://chriswiegman.com/2019/12/keeping-docker-containers-updated/